# How to get the blue box of speech recognition while using inproc speech recogniton in sapi?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, speech-recognition, sapi

I am working with sapi 5.4 and the IspRecognizer i am currently using is a instance of  CLSID_SpInprocRecognizer instead of CLSID_SpSharedRecognizer and after I started using this the default blue box of windows recognition is not appearing any more. How can i be in in proc speech recognition and get the blue box for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSR UX is only available with the shared recognizer.  It's intentionally not available with inproc recognizers for a variety of reasons:

- To allow developers a way to build custom speech experiences w/o interference from WSR
- Inproc recognizers can be configured with SR engines that aren't supported by WSR
- WSR assumes that the default microphone is being used, which isn't necessarily the case with inproc recognizers